# LinkedIn API Unable to retrieve access token with product "Sign In with LinkedIn"

Tags: linkedin-api

Integrate with API https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken and get error response.
Response:
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Unable to retrieve access token:
appid/redirect uri/code verifier does not match authorization code. Or authorization code expired.
Or external member binding exists"}[Sign In with LinkedIn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fzrE.png)

LinkedIn support redirect me to here. As product "Sign In with LinkedIn" is deprecated, gonna remove the product "Sign In with LinkedIn" at existing app?

App with product "Sign In with LinkedIn" is not working, if app with product "Sign In with LinkedIn using OpenID Connect" is working,
but app with both products is not working.

May I know any solution to fix?
Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.